# Effect of PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES on duplicated key insert/updates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The below insert query works fine when `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is true, but results in a `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number` when set to false.  Is this to be expected?  Is it always good practice to include a separate index with identical value in the array when the query uses the same value twice?  For instance, `$sql='INSERT INTO t1(id,v1) VALUES(:id,:v1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v1=:v1_dup'; ... $stmt->execute(array('id'=>1,'v1'=>123, 'v1_dup'=>123));` Don't know if it matters, but I am using PHP's native mysqlnd driver for MySQL.

```
<?php
    class db
    {
        private static $instance = NULL;
        private function __construct() {}   //Make private
        private function __clone(){}   //Make private
        public static function db() //Get instance of DB
        {
            if (!self::$instance)
            {
                  try{self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8",'myUser','myPW',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));}
                //try{self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8",'myUser','myPW',array(                                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));}
                catch(PDOException $e){die(library::sql_error($e));}
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }

    try{
        $sql = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, v1 INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id) )';
        db::db()->exec($sql);

        $sql='INSERT INTO t1(id,v1) VALUES(:id,:v1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v1=:v1';
        $stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array('id'=>1,'v1'=>123));
        $stmt->execute(array('id'=>1,'v1'=>321));

        $stmt=db::db()->query('SELECT * FROM t1');
        $rs=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo('<pre>'.print_r($rs,1).'</pre>');


    }
    catch(PDOException $e){die('<pre>'.print_r($e,1).'</pre>');}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

For the reason phrased like "this feature may cause unexpected behavior", multiple binding was turned off for the native prepared statements.

Just bind it using another placeholder

```
$sql='INSERT INTO t1(id,v1) VALUES(:id,:v1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v1=:v1d';
$stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('id'=>1,'v1'=>123,'v1d'=>123));
$stmt->execute(array('id'=>1,'v1'=>321,'v1d'=>321));
```

or

you can use mysql-way:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO t1(id,v1) VALUES(:id,:v1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v1=values(v1)';
```

Comment: Thanks My Common Sense,  I expected so much, but wasn't sure.  Probably best to do so regardless of using native prepared statements, agree?  Where did you find "this feature may cause unexpected behavior" regarding it?

Comment: I can't remember exactly. Somewhere in mailing PHP lists I believe. Yes, I would create different placeholders to make code less ambiguous. Though many people find this ability (to bind single value to many placeholders) quite useful.

Comment: Thought for this particular case of insert on duplicate, I would use mysql approach